# Help with thevenins voltage

Tags: thevenin

### Have to find the power developing on the 7k resistor (I*U).

Calculated (hopefully correct) **R**thevenin to be 12k//4k which would be 3k.
Circuit simulator shows that the current through the resistor should be 3mA but i can't figure out how to get to that number with the voltages provided, seeming as i would need my **U**thevenin to be 30 volts for that to work (afaik).

What am i missing?

[image: The circuit]

Comment: Just to note, the top and bottom sources were current sources that were transformed into voltage sources (6mA top and 4mA bottom).

Comment: Use the approach found by Helmholtz: [link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/superposition-theorem/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the original (pre-modification) schematic, as I gather it from your schematic, and then show the transformation. I'm doing this just to make sure that I understand what you say you did:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9OXBz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I missed something, let me know.

At this point, it's helpful to redraw things:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAheDf.png)</sup>

All I did in the above-left case was to add a ground reference. You can do this to exactly one node, only. But you are free to choose any one node. I chose the one you see.

In the above-right case, all I did was move things around a little bit. You should be able to see what I did and agree that the choices I made are legitimate.

We are now in a position to combine some resistors and voltage sources and greatly simplify the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMJDcc.png)</sup>

At this point, you should have a very easy time working out the current in \$R_4\$.

Comment: Thank you both for answering, helped a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the equivalent Thevenin voltage source.

To do that, you have to assume no current goes out of you circuit, i. e., no current flowing through the 7kΩ resistor.

The bottom left part is equivalent to 48V source and 12kΩ resistance; the top right part is equivalent to 24V source and 4kΩ resistance.

When you connect these two sides in parallel, the voltage will be somewhere between 24V and 48V. You have a voltage divider formed by 12kΩ connected to 48V and 4kΩ connected to 24V. The voltage difference is 48V-24V=24V. The voltage drop over the 4kΩ resistance will be 24V*4kΩ/(12kΩ+4kΩ)=6V. So the output voltage will be 24V+6V=30V, as you were suspecting.

Comment: Thanks for answering, think i get it but will run through it again in the morning. Can't think straight atm.